# iOS List separator margin issue on NativeScript

Tags: ios, nativescript

I'm working on a iOS application using NativeScript. I would like to know how to resolve the list separator margin issue:
[image: List issue]

Answer (score 3):

In NativeScript you can only change the color of the separator with the property `separatorColor`
However you can use the native iOS API to change the default separator margins (one of the benefits using NativeScript is access to the native APIs) Here is an example code :

```
function onLoaded(args) {
    page = args.object;
    page.bindingContext = { "items": allItemsViewModel };

    var listView = page.getViewById("all-items");
    var tableView = listView.ios;
    for (var i = 0; i < allItemsViewModel.length; i++) {
        var cellIndexPath = NSIndexPath.indexPathForItemInSection(i, 0);
        var cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(cellIndexPath);
        if (cell !== null) {
            cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false;
            cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
            cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Or you could just set the separator color to transparent

```
<ListView items="{{ itemsArray}}" separatorColor="#00000000">
```

Then in the `itemTemplate` you create your own separator and control the margin, height, color, ect directly from xml:

```
<ListView.itemTemplate>
  <StackLayout>
     ...
     <StackLayout backgroundColor="#708090" height="1"/>
  <StackLayout>
</ListView.itemTemplate>
```